# global name is not defined error

Tags: python, global

My code:

```
import sys
import time
import random


def main():
    print('***TEST**** Grad School Multiplier=',gradschoolmultiplier,'***TEST***')
    x=gradschoolmultiplier*50000
    print('Your salary in dollars, $',x)

def start():    
    gradschool=input('Do you intend to go to Graduate School? ')
    print('')
    time.sleep(2)
    if gradschool=='yes':print('That is a fantastic if expensive decision.')
    elif gradschool=='Yes':print('That is a fantastic if expensive decision.')
    elif gradschool=='Y':print('That is a fantastic if expensive decision.')
    elif gradschool=='y':print('That is a fantastic if expensive decision.')
    elif gradschool=='YES':print('That is a fantastic if expensive decision.')
    else:print('No?  Well, then it\'s off to work to pay back those student loans.')
    print('')
    if gradschool=='yes':g1=3
    elif gradschool=='Yes':g1=3
    elif gradschool=='Y':g1=3
    elif gradschool=='y':g1=3
    elif gradschool=='YES':g1=3
    else:g1=1
    g=random.randrange(1, 3)
    if g==1:gradschoolmultiplier=1
    else:gradschoolmultiplier=g1*g/2
    time.sleep(2)
    main()

start()
```

And of course I get:

```
NameError: global name 'gradschoolmultiplier' is not defined
```

I am not smart enough to understand the answers to this question for others.  Would someone be so kind as to explain the answer in simpletons' terms?  Thanks!

Comment: Try `if gradschool.lower() in ("y", "yes")` and put in a line break after each `:`, then combine your `print` and assignment of `g1` into the same block.

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ - you REALLY need to read and understand this document. Also, if you repeat the exact same code multiple times YOU ARE DOING SOMETHING WRONG (see @jonrsharpe's comment). Having a `main` method but using `start()` as the "main" method is a bad idea, too...

Answer (score 2):

Indeed as @Dan says, the scoping problem.

Or you can use `global` variables.

Some of my other suggestions on your code:

```
import sys
import time
import random


def print_salary():
    print('***TEST**** Grad School Multiplier=',gradschoolmultiplier,'***TEST***')
    x = gradschoolmultiplier*50000
    print('Your salary in dollars, $',x)

def main():    
    gradschool=input('Do you intend to go to Graduate School? ')
    print('')
    time.sleep(2)

    if gradschool.lower() in {'yes', 'y'}:
        print('That is a fantastic if expensive decision.')
        g1 = 3
    else:
        print('No?  Well, then it\'s off to work to pay back those student loans.')
        g1 = 1
    print('')

    g = random.randrange(1, 3)
    global gradschoolmultiplier
    if g == 1:
        gradschoolmultiplier = 1
    else:
        gradschoolmultiplier = g1 * g / 2
    time.sleep(2)
    print_salary()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You should combine some the `if` statements to make it simpler.

Oh, we share the same thoughts @jonrsharpe

Quick improvement as suggested by @Nils

Comment: Why not use a tuple or set literal instead of those lists? `if blah in {'yes', 'y'}`

Comment: Yeah! Sets are better.

Comment: I would recommend renaming `start()` to `main()` and `main()` to maybe `print_salary()`. Also in the last line I would recommnd using `if __name__ == '__main__': main()`

Answer (score 1):

`gradschoolmultiplier` is not in the scope of `main()`, it only exists in `start()`.

You can pass it into main.

change the call to main to be `main(gradschoolmultiplier)`

change `def main()` to `def main(gradschoolmultiplier):`

[Information on python scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/27604)

Comment: You are a genius!  Thank you.  Would you be so kind as to explain what the def main() is doing vs. def main(gradschoolmultiplier)?

Comment: `def main(a)` means that when main is called, it expects 1 variable to be passed into it, and in the code of `main()` that variable will be referred to as `a`. `main()` is not expecting anything to be passed to it.